# CSS class selector wildcard

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I was wondering if there was a way to throw a wildcard into my CSS?

I have several classes that are `.button-0`, `.button-1`, `.button-2`, `.button-3`, etc. within a `button` element. I want to get all the `.button-*` classes to define.

Is it possible to do something like:

```css
button .button-[=*] {
  margin-right: 2rem;  
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
button [class*="button-"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;  
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3L5urep/)

---

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> `[attr*=value]` - Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

```css
button [class*="button-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span class="button-0">text</span>
    <span class="button-1">text</span>
    <span class="button-2">text</span>
</button>
```

As [Chad points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812670/css-class-selector-wildcard/28812711?noredirect=1#comment45897780_28812711), it is entirely possible that an element can contain a class such as `this-is-my-button-class`. In which case, that undesired element would be selected. In order to prevent this, you could use a combination of two selectors:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m15yj74m/)

```
button [class^="button-"],
button [class*=" button-"] {
  margin-right: 2rem;  
}
```

The selector `button [class^="button-"]` ensures that the element will be selected if it starts with `button-`. Since it's possible the element's first class doesn't start with `button-`, the selector `[class*=" button-"]` (note the whitespace), ensures that it will be selected.

Comment: That will work, but to start a selector with a string you should use the `^` selector, like `button [class^="button-"]`.

Comment: @Chad ..what if the element has [multiple classes](http://jsfiddle.net/L74fvd0a/) and `button-` isn't the first class? In that case `^` wouldn't work.

Comment: @JoshCrozier but what if he has a class like `this-is-my-button-class`?

Comment: @JoshCrozier You could hack it a bit, and do a double selector like: `div[class^="button-"], div[class*=" button-"]`, making sure to grab the first one or one that has a space preceding it. (I'm playing devil's advocate here)

Comment: @Chad: That is the most foolproof answer.

Comment: @Chad Thanks. I completely forgot about that option. Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
button[id|=button]{
    color:red;
}
```

All buttons whose id contain the word **button** will get affected. For example http://jsfiddle.net/czp28jpb/

Comment: Actually that's the CSS2 spec, and does not base off of a string, so if he wanted to be sure that it had a dash (like if a button was called `<button class="btn btn-gray">`, this solution wouldn't work.