# Dynamic css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I try to style something this:

```
span#wdps_0_slide4633_layer1.none.wdps_animated
```

The dynamic value is **slideXXXX**

How can I write it to style any silde number?

Comment: Do any other elements have the 'wdps_animated' class? If not, `span.wdps_animated { blah: blah }` would work.

Comment: The closest you can get is `span[id^=wdps_o_slide]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a whole bunch of CSS wildcards to use in your selectors.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Please take a read on that and on the lots of duplicate questions like this:

[CSS class selector wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28812670/css-class-selector-wildcard)

or this:

[Is there a CSS selector by class prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338680/is-there-a-css-selector-by-class-prefix)

Comment: Use flags to indicate duplicate questions, not answers. (But you don't have to for this question, because I'm picking a more suitable duplicate.)

Comment: thanks and sorry @BoltClock